# How to use overloaded input operator for some inputs and normal input operator for other inputs?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out how you can overload the input operator for some input but use the normal input operator for other values. For instance,

```
cin >> a; //take in a normally
in >> b; //pass with the overloaded input operator
```

How do I differentiate when writing the overloaded operator function?

Comment: If `a` and `b` are the same type, you can't differentiate. From that you may infer that the differentiator is the data's type.

Comment: In the above linked question, see specifically [stream operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719) where you can define `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, T& obj)` for your object